# Oracle performance- am I better starting off with the smallest result set

Tags: performance, oracle, join

Just having a discussion with some blokes at work about the best way to write queries and performance.

Is it better to limit your very first result set, so that all the joins from the initial table have less rows to join onto?

For example:

TABLE: REFCODE has ~10,000 rows

TABLE: WHSE has ~200 rows

Which is better for performance?

Using an inner join to squeeze the rows out of the large result set:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  REFCODE
INNER JOIN
  WHSE ON
  WHSE.RCIDX = REFCODE.RCIDX
```

Using the smaller resultset first:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  WHSE
INNER JOIN
  REFCODE ON
  REFCODE.RCIDX = WHSE.RCIDX
```

Using the largest resultset, but using a where clause the filter only records that I know will join to the second table

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  REFCODE
INNER JOIN
  WHSE ON
  WHSE.RCIDX = REFCODE.RCIDX
WHERE
  REFCODE.TYPE = 'WHSE'
```

Or will the CBO determine an explain plan similar?
I've been told by the guys here at work that you should always start with the smallest resultset possible, but not sure!

Any discussion appreaciated!

Comment: The actual order of tables specified in the from clause have no impact to performance. I say your peers are over thinking things and are trying to optimize without facts. Just write the query as needed to get the results you need. Look at an Explain Plan or TKProf file for both versions of your first two queries, the CBO will parse the statements and most likely have the same execution plans. Adding a predicate will change the execution plan again because it's now a different query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple case like the one you posted, the optimizer will almost certainly generate the same query plan for all three queries.  There will be no difference in performance.

In general, the order of tables in the query is irrelevant.  The optimizer should figure out the appropriate join order and join method(s) based on the statistics you have gathered on the objects.  Occasionally, when you are joining relatively large numbers of tables, the optimizer won't be able to consider every possible join order because doing so would require exceeding the `optimizer_max_permutations` setting.  When that happens, the optimizer uses heuristics to try to determine which paths to consider in detail and which to ignore.  Those heuristics are imperfect so you may find that there are cases where the optimizer eliminates a path that would have lead to a better join order.  Listing the most restrictive tables first can produce a bias toward plans where that is the driving table which are likely to be the most efficient.  But that is very much a corner case.

Jonathan Lewis has a nice article on how [the order of tables in the `FROM` clause can affect the query plan](http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2006/11/03/table-order/).  But for the vast majority of queries you are likely to write or to encounter, the order of tables is irrelevant.

Back in the old rule-based optimizer days when Oracle 7.3.4 was shiny and new and dinosaurs roamed the Earth, the rule-based optimizer would use the order of tables to generate the plan.  I'll wager that the folks that you're talking to are either old enough to have been around in those days or are passing down rules they were taught by those old developers.

Even though there is no longer (in almost all cases) any performance benefit, a consistent approach to structuring your queries can be beneficial.  If you always put the leading tables first, for example, that may encourage developers to think about the expected query plan and write their code a bit more thoughtfully.  And it can make it easier to see relatively quickly if the optimizer is doing what you expect when it generates the query plan in order to clue you in to issues with the statistics that you have on your objects.

Comment: Great answer! And you are very correct about the colleague being around in those days. The explain plan between the first 2 was exactly the same, but the explain plan from the 3rd was different (And a slightly less cost)